# woocommerce how to hook into checkout page

Tags: woocommerce, hook, checkout

I would like to add additional information / update the checkout table in woocommerce. This is the table i mean:

[image]

I would like to edit the quantity and the title of the product.

I have had a look into woocommerce hooks and came across the following:

```
woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantit
```

So i made a test function to have a play:

```
function add_meta_on_checkout_order_review_item( $quantity , $cart_item , $cart_item_key  ) {   
    echo $cart_item[ 'quantity' ] + 5;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'add_meta_on_checkout_order_review_item', 1, 3 );
```

This however has no effect. Am i hooking into the right woocommerce hook?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this: `add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'add_meta_on_checkout_order_review_item', 1, 3 );`
To this : `add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'add_meta_on_checkout_order_review_item', 10, 3 );`

You can also try to return instead of echo the quantity.

Comment: hi, this makes no difference. As for echoing / returning this makes no difference either

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am little late here but you can try this:-

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name','add_meta_on_checkout_order_review_item',10,3);
```

And this would surely help to add the meta data under the Title of the product.

Thanks,